# How can conditional deployment of a contract be done?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps

This might be a very basic query, but, I would like to know how I can restrict the deployment of contracts based on some condition. More specifically, assume that I have an "Admin" who can assign "Creator" roles to certain addresses. These creators should be able to deploy a "Creation" contract. Non-creators should be incapable of doing the same.

How can I impose a set of conditions which determine whether or not a contract will be deployed or not?

Comment: Please share all the relevant details from your code. The question is too generic and not focused enough. "`How should the design of the contracts be`" sounds more like - please do the entire work for me. You can, for example, show what you've designed and implemented so far, and then ask a more specific question about some technical issue that you are finding difficult to resolve.

Comment: @goodvibration My approach was to introduce an "onlyCreator()" modifier in the constructor of the "Creation" contract. However, I am not sure if this is the recommended design pattern to be followed.

Comment: Please add those details **in your question**. Also, what you've just described doesn't quite sound like **all** the relevant details, just a very small portion of them. "`How can I impose a set of conditions which determine whether or not a contract will be deployed or not?`" - use an if/else statement (I hope that this answer makes it easier for you to understand why more details are needed here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new AccessControl in Openzeppelin 3.0.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.5;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";

contract A is AccessControl {

    event EventCreated(address creator, uint value);

    modifier onlyCreator(address account) {
        require(hasRole(CREATOR_ROLE, account), "Only creators allowed");
        _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        _setupRole(CREATOR_ROLE, msg.sender);
    }

    function createEvent(uint amount) public onlyCreator(msg.sender) {
        emit EventCreated(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```

For more details check the [documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/access-control).